# Where can I find the origin of this error?

Tags: visual-workflow, error, fields, invalid

Trying to create a ServiceResource assigned to a ServiceAppointment in Flow createRecords element, I get this error:

```
FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: 
INVALID_FIELD: This Service Resource is inactive. 
You can only assign Service Appointment to active Service Resources.
```

Problem is that I don't know the origin of this error. It's thrown just in BeforeInsert time in AssignedResource object Trigger. Is not a Validation Rule. I'm not sure if it's a Lookup filter error.

Where INVALID_FIELD errors are created?

Comment: There is a process builder or Flow that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Flow that it's been trigger in which you are assigning a Service Appointment to a Service Resource that is not active.

Comment: or Process Builder